# Use Greek letters in URL in GET request

Tags: android, delphi, indy, idhttp

I'm developing an Android app in Delphi 10.4. My client communicates with the server through web services.

I use a search-by-name service with the GET method to take a list of names depending on what letter, English or Greek, I type in a `TEdit`. The line of code looks like this:

```
mydata := IdHTTP1.GET('http://.../Names/search/'+Edit1.Text);
```

The request is called every time the user types a letter in the `TEdit`, and returns the names that start with the first letter(s) of the text that the user typed.

When I use English letters, the search works fine, but when I use Greek letters, it doesn't work properly. Instead, it returns all the list of names <sup>1</sup>.

I try the path in a browser using Greek letters, like this: `http://.../Names/search/Αντ`, and it works, it returns the names starting with `Αντ`. But in the app, it doesn't work.

Is it possible that the encoding of the `TEdit` or `TIdHTTP` component are wrong?

It's like it doesn't read the Greek letters and sends an empty string.

<sup>1</sup> Because if the path is: `http://.../Names/search/`, it returns all the list of names.

My code looks like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1ChangeTracking(Sender: TObject);
var
  mydata : string;
  jsv,js : TJSONValue;
  originalObj,jso : TJSONObject;
  jsa : TJSONArray;
  i: Integer;

begin
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  try

     IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
     IdHTTP1.Request.CharSet := 'utf-8';
     IdHTTP1.Request.AcceptLanguage := 'gr';  
     IdHTTP1.Request.ContentEncoding  := 'UTF-8';
 
     mydata := IdHTTP1.Get('http://.../Names/search/'+Edit1.Text);

  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
    end;
  end;

  try
    jsv := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mydata),0) as TJSONValue;
    try
      jsa := jsv as TJSONArray;
      for i := 0 to jsa.Size-1 do
      begin
        jso := jsa.Get(I) as TJSONObject;
        js :=  jso.Get('Name').JsonValue;
        Memo1.Lines.Add(js.Value);
         if i=4 then  // show the 5 first names of the search
           break;
       end;
     finally
       jsv.Free();
     end;
  except
    on E: exception do
    begin
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

URLs can't contain *unencoded* non-ASCII characters. You can't just append the `TEdit` text as-is, you need to url-encode any non-ASCII characters, as well as characters reserved by the URI specs.

If you use your browser's built-in debugger, you will see that it is actually doing this encoding when transmitting the request to the server. For example, a URL like: `http://.../Names/search/Αντ` sends a request like this:

```http
GET /Names/search/%CE%91%CE%BD%CF%84 HTTP/1.1
Host: ...
...
```

Notice `Αντ` => `%CE%91%CE%BD%CF%84`

In your code, you can use Indy's `TIdURI` class for this purpose, eg:

```
uses
  ..., IdURI;

mydata := IdHTTP1.GET('http://.../Names/search/'+TIdURI.PathEncode(Edit1.Text));
```

---

On a side note:

Since you are sending a GET request, you do not need to set the `Request.ContentType`, `Request.CharSet`, or `Request.ContentEncoding` properties (besides, `'UTF-8'` is not valid for `ContentEncoding` anyway).

Also, `ParseJSONValue()` has an overload that takes a `string`, so you don't need to use `TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes()`.